# Java if null{return} gets turned in if else after compile/decompile

Tags: java, android, performance

TL;Dr, scroll to the last **Edit**. I'm leaving this all here so people can read from what this discussion evolved.

I've got the following code for a library:

```
private void addData(JSONObject jsonObject) {
    if (jsonObject == null){
        return;
    }
    if (jsonObject.has("elements")){
        try {
            addData(jsonObject.getJSONArray("elements"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }else{
        try {
            getArray().put(jsonObject);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Now in Android Studio, I use this library. When I go into it (by pressing ctrl+b to go to the definition of functions), I see that it decompiles it to this:

```
private void addData(JSONObject jsonObject) {
    if(jsonObject != null) {
        if(jsonObject.has("elements")) {
            try {
                this.addData(jsonObject.getJSONArray("elements"));
            } catch (JSONException var3) {
                var3.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            try {
                this.getArray().put(jsonObject);
            } catch (JSONException var4) {
                ;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I know that effectively it's the same, but in my mind this would affect performance. My code would be faster if `jsonObject` is null often, (as it doesn't have to jump to the end of the function and then jump out of it, as the second version does,) and the second version is more efficient if `jsonObject` is not `null` more often.

Am I right on my statement of changing performance, and what is the reason Java compiles it like this?

**Edit:**
Okay, as I'm seeing some replies stating that it's exactly the same, let me elaborate a bit further. I've had multiple courses in C and C++. These languages get translated to assembly right away, making it easy to see exactly all the jumps.

Say we've got this pseudo-code:

```
function a(){
    //p 1
    b();
    //p2
}
function b(){
    if (something){
        return;
    }
}
```

This would get compiled into:

```
function a(){
    //p1
    b(); //jump to b()
    //p2
}
function b(){
    if (something){//if not, jump to. If, don't jump } (1st jump)
        goto whereyoucamefrom;//whereyoucamefrom in this case is b(); in function a(), so it'll jump to p2 (1st jump)
    }
    goto whereyoucamefrom;//whereyoucamefrom is now also b();, so going to p2 again. (2nd jump, only when not something.)
}
```

This results in 1 jump if something is true, 2 if something is false. That definitely looks more efficient to me than:

```
function b(){
    if (!something){//if not, jump to else (1st jump)
        //body of function
        goto afterelse;
    }else{//if the body got executed, jump to } (1st jump)
        goto endoffunction;
    }


    goto whereyoucamefrom;//this is endoffunction (2nd jump, always gets executed)
}
```

which will always result in 2 jumps.

**Edit:**
Okay, I'm going to try to use this edit to clarify (once more) my intention with this post.

My question is concerning optimization on jump (or goto) level. My question is, is it true that

```
function a(){
    if (something){
        jump out of function;
    }
    //body
    jump out of function;
}
```

is faster than

```
function a(){
    if (something){
        jump over else
    }else{
        //body
    }
    jump out of function
}
```

? And if so, why doesn't the java compiler do this correctly? See the original post for my written code and a `decompiled` version of the compiled version.

Comment: seems to be a nice question, who the heck downvoted ?

Comment: Performance should be the same. You have to check `jsonObject` at least once to determin whether it is `null`. The decompiled code is a little bit nicer in my oppinion since it leaves the method on only one branch (no `return;` needed).

Comment: @Turing85 I know you have to check if null, but I'm also considering jumps here. A jump (or goto) is pretty expensive on the processor when it gets executed, as it has to flush the pipe, taking at least 3, up to something like 20 clockcycles.

Comment: @VividVervet I, the heck, downvoted. Give me time before asking :) 1/ Sprinkling "return" inside code is bad practice. Natural return is end of method. Readers have a harder time working out what's hapenning. 2/ Compiler optimisation is right 99% of the time. 3/ OP seems to think that because the end of his code is bypassed he "saves time". Against all logic. I'm not a professionnal downvoter. Check my record. But this time I feel a genuine lack of trying.

Comment: @AlainPannetier should some one need to ask you this ? you can say this when you downvoted

Comment: @VividVervet, I was already commenting when you asked.

Comment: Without starting a religious war, returning early isn't by default bad practice; it's clearly an opinionated statement.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils, It generally shows lack of logic structuring.  You can avoid this 99% of the time. Proof? Compiler got rid of it.

Comment: @AlainPannetier I think my code is more readable and more structured. Reading top to bottom:
If jsonObject == null do nothing.
With only one return:
if jsonObject == null... scroll down.... scroll down... find matching }.... Ah, do nothing.
Personal preference.

Comment: @DaniëlvandenBerg, what prevented you from putting your second "try" block inside an else block?

Comment: That's not proof unless you're trying to prove you can spend a lot of time trying to be a human compiler. I realize it can be avoided. In fact, 99% of the time is ~1% inaccurate. The point is there are many cases when it makes no sense to attempt to avoid it. Recursive inserts on most data structs are a perfect example. A tree for instance would need time & space to create a temp variable only to allow needless conditional checks. Sure, you can make it ugly which is more of a case of needing to modularize a solution. @AlainPannetier

Comment: @AlainPannetier Aaaah, now I finally get your point. That wasn't mine. Hang on, I'll edit my code a bit to make the question more clear. I'm really focussing on the first if statement.

Comment: @DaniëlvandenBerg, so what you need is if {} else if {} else. Still no need for "return" still. Respect the maintainer. Especially if it's you.

Comment: @AlainPannetier That would still jump to after the last else, and from there out of the function. This really is more a theoretical question than a practical one, I really am just wondering if I'm wrong about the jump count, or if there's a way to check that.

Comment: @DaniëlvandenBerg, what about if if (jsonObject != null && jsonObject.has("elements")) { stuff } else { more stuff };

Comment: Removed the downvote so that every one smiles again :)

Comment: @AlainPannetier What it would do is continue running if that's all true, otherwise jump over the body, and then out of the function. With an inverted check with a return it'd jump right out of the function, instead of first over the body. I do, as said, not know if this is maybe optimized out at a lower level (as suggested might be the case by @Zoyd).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a fairly common strategy for microprocessors to 1) use a pipeline, 2) preload code that will be executed later, to turn it into their internal representation and, in some architectures, executing it in advance. Branches are a problem for both, which is the whole point of branch prediction. Typically, the right thing to do for a programmer is to reduce the number of branches and put the code that is expected to run most ofen in the "then" branch of an if-then-else statement, because processors often "bet" that this will happen.

That said, in reality, performance depends on a whole lot of very unpredictable parameters. For example, if your "optimized" code is compiled to a slightly longer machine code sequence, this might cause a cache miss and cause it to be slower. Or it may cause your longer code to be better aligned and thus faster. Or something else, because the code is run on a Friday morning.

Also, you showed the "compiled" Java code, but what about compiled JVM assembly code ? If the compiler performs flow analysis, it may detect that the "else" branch goes directly to the end of the method, and replace it with a return. Or not, because it may be more efficient, but then again, it may not be.

And of course, all this does not even begin to take into account the fact that Java runs on extremely different architectures on which everything I wrote above may be wrong.

In my opinion, writing if-then-else blocks with the most commonly executed code in the "then" branch and avoiding to beak the code flow whenever reasonably possible leads to clear, easily read code. It also happens to be typically more efficient, so I definitely recommend it. Of course, like all recommendations, this one should not be treated as a hard rule.

Answer (score 2):

```
public void method1(JSONObject jsonObject) {     
    if (jsonObject == null){
        return;
        //end
    }
    //do stuff
}
```

and

```
public void method2(JSONObject jsonObject) {
    if(jsonObject != null) {
      //do stuff 
    }
    //end
}
```

is the same. There is no performance difference. I think your code is not more efficient when `jsonObject` is often null, as you say.

Comment: As I elaborated in my edit, `//end` is also needed in the first method, after `do stuff`. This would cause 2 jumps in the second, over 1 (`if (jsonObject == null)` **or** 2 (otherwise) in the first.